# Getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function` while using sweet alerts 2

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am using Sweet alerts 2 in a delete function. The code is working fine, Getting the alert but when I am clicking on the delete button of the alert I am getting an error in the console. Not getting this error while clicking on the cancel button. I am using this for the first time so I don't know why I am getting this error.

Sweet Alerts 2  -> https://sweetalert2.github.io/

error ->

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

My js function ->

```
function onDelete(){
      swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "url",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        id: 2
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        swal.fire("Done!", "It was succesfully deleted!", "success");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        swal.fire("Error deleting!", "Please try again", "error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
 }
```

Comment: Your code looks good, are you sure the error is caused by this function?

Comment: @YorkChen I only used sweet alerts in this function

Comment: you can see which line of code happens the error by clicking the error in console.

Answer (score 2):

Just Make sure anywhere else in your code you dont have a sweet alert code, i.e. Mixing `swal()` for **Sweetalert** and `swal.fire()` for **Sweetalert2**.

it will return the error you have just described.